# Log rotation: application do not write to truncated new log file

Tags: linux, logrotate, log-rotation

I trust you all doing good.

we planning to implement log rotation for below file.
`stdout.log`

we use below log rotation configuration file.

```
/usr/local/rms/kafka/kafka-connect-fluentd/stdout.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    maxsize 100M
    minsize 10M
    copytruncate
    delaycompress
    compress
    notifempty
    missingok
}
```

we have noticed the file is rotating and file is truncated.But application does not write logs to new file.
we tried to send the HUP signal and it did not work.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 appuser appuser 8.2M Feb 20 03:11 stdout.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 appuser appuser 4.0M Feb 20 23:48 stdout.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 appuser appuser 7.6M Feb 20 23:49 stdout.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 appuser appuser 2.1G Feb 21 03:39 stdout.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 appuser appuser 2.2G Feb 21 14:15 stdout.log
```

The application itself do not have a reload option, We stop the application and start the application when we need to reload or restart the application.

we use below command to bring up the application

```
nohup connect-standalone ${BASE}/connect-standalone.properties 
${BASE}/FluentdSourceConnector.properties >& ${BASE}/stdout.log &
```

we use below command to kill the application

```
kill -9 <processid>
```

How do we implement a log rotating mechanism for this situation ?

Comment: `>& ${BASE}/stdout.log` - you want the log to truncate on each restart? It would be better to use the standard `2>&1 >> ${BASE}/stdout.log` then nonstandard `>&`

Comment: @KamilCuk this was helped full and resolved my issue. If you do not mind could you please do little bit elaboration

Answer (score 1):

```
>& FILE
```

Is the [obsolete syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) for:

```
> FILE 2>&1
```

The `> FILE` [redirects](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) standard output of the command to file named `FILE`. However, before that happens, "if the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size".

So each time you restarted your command, your file was (properly) truncated by the shell. What you want is to append to the file. Do that by using `>>` redirection. Including that you want to redirect both stdout and stderr, use:

```
2>&1 >>FILE
```

The `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout and the `>>FILE` appends stdout to `FILE`.